# Django 1.6 request POST/GET empty

Tags: django, django-forms

I use a function-based view and try to validate a form which is submitted over Ajax (with jquery.form plugin):

```
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-CSRFToken:jRr4oOBHQS5mtwopN69xHocjWJBYuJHa
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Request payload:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken=jRr4oOBHQS5mtwopN69xHocjWJBYuJHa&code=123456
```

now, in the view function, I have request.GET/POST empty, but request.body as a string, and I can't validate the form.

```
form = CodeCheckForm(parse_qs(request.body))
form.is_valid()
```

In the second line, the clean* functions aren't called, which is really weird.

Changing to use `data` or `initial` doesn't help either:

```
form = CodeCheckForm(data=parse_qs(request.body))
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** among the answers, the decisive was to change the content type. In jquery.forms plugin I set `contentType` option to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`.

**EDIT 2:** there are 2 ways to supply arbitrary data around the standard way, but they weren't suitable in my case:

1) `form = MyForm(parse_qs(request.body))` is almost correct, but Django forms expect this to be a QueryDict, and have some properties, while this is a usual dict. Form class raises exception and crashes the view.

2) `form = MyForm(data=parse_qs(request.body))` works, but does not call `clean*` functions. This is intentional, as Django developers made this way as a way **around clean functions**. You're supposed to validate the data yourself, and then submit it this way. Django form then does not clean it in any way and decides the form is not validated, hence `form.is_valid()` will be `False`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GET and [POST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) only contain form data. They are empty for you because your content type is 'application/json'. It's not clear to me why you've used this content type, since the payload looks like form encoded data to me, not json.

If you manually parse the payload, use the `data` argument. The `initial` argument is only used to show initial values. If you don't bind the form to data, then the form is unbound, and will never be valid.

I'm not sure why the following line didn't work. What is the value of `parse_qs(request.body)`?

```
form = CodeCheckForm(parse_qs(request.body))
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot the `data` attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work as needed. If I call Form(data=parse_qs(...)), then clean method doesn't work at all. So, it's better to make jquery.form submit it with proper content type.

Comment: ok, setting contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' made it work. Thanks!

Comment: I meant to say that the form will never be valid if you set `initial` instead of `data`. The first argument is `data`, so `form = CodeCheckForm(parse_qs(request.body))` and `form = CodeCheckForm(data=parse_qs(request.body))` are the same. I'm still not sure why that line didn't work, but glad to hear you solved your problem by setting the content type.

Comment: The first way does not work, because form expects it to have some QueryDict properties, and raises exceptions, which leads to the 500. The second way you're supposed to clean the data yourself, and clean functions don't work.

Comment: I don't think that's right. The two lines are the same, whether or not you use named arguments. Whichever line you use, you always need to call `form.is_valid()` to clean the form. Most forms will validate fine if you provide a dictionary instead of a query dict - if there's an exception then it's something specific to your form.

Comment: I checked it and introspected the form class and even django form class. The reason is that self.clean_data is empty right away, when django.forms.Form.clean is called. I didn't override `clean`.